# Android : Start an activity when user clicks on a Whatsapp conversation

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there any way through which I can start an Activity of my application when a user clicks on any conversation in his Whatsapp app ?
(Basically, my app should start when he clicks on some conversation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of obvious privacy issues you can't monitor intents system wide. So basically: No, you can't do that.